# how to display list response in dialogflow bot

Tags: list, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I want to display a list of data from firebase realtime database in the dialogflow web bot

eg:
 **user** - i need top 3 selling books
**Bot** - below are details of top selling books

```
 - Anna Karenina by Leo Tolstoy
 - The Great Gatsby by F. Scott Fitzgerald
 - Hamlet by William Shakespeare
```

where the database has following data in **firebase realtime database** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4cwV.png

**Note**: I want to display this bulleted list in default web bot (not google assistant or FB or slack integration)

Have tried below functions, but didn't work

try 1:

```
return admin.database().ref('books').once("child_added").then((data) => {
      agent.add(`${data.val().title} => ${data.val().author}`);
    }); // this displays only 1st row of DB
```

try 2:

```
 return admin.database().ref('books').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  let books_list = snapshot.val();
    agent.add(`${holiday_list}`);
}); // this displays the output in json format including the key which is not required
```

try 3:

```
var bookRef = firebase.database().ref("books/");
    
    playersRef.orderByChild("title").on("child_added", function(data) {
       console.log(`${data.val().title} by ${data.val().author}`);
agent.add(`${data.val().title} by ${data.val().author}`);
});// this prints the required result, but in google cloud console and not in chat-bot
```

any help is appreciated